# Issue while installing Docker Desktop on windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install Docker Desktop on windows 10 using wsl backend but I'm continuously getting no suitable backend available error. can someone help me in troubleshooting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For installing docker desktop in your windows 10 machine with wsl as backend you need to have wsl to upgrade to version 2 and we also need to download a distro supported by wsl to or you can upgrade the existing distro to version 2. for more information you go through the following [link](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/)